# Adding fragments of Different height to a Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I followed exactly [this link at androidhive of simple tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) and created a tab layout with fragments of different heights. The tab layout is inside coordinator layout along with view pager. I have some **textview**s after the coordinator layout. And I want coordinator layout to take only space required by fragments, so that **textview**s is shown adjacent to even the **shorter** fragment. But using wrap_content in height of coordinator hides the fragments and only shows tab titles. If I set height to 1000dp, it shows both fragments but there is lot of blank space between smaller fragment and textview. How and what should I set height to get desired result?
I will paste code if required. 
[image: Current situation]

I currently have this situation with smaller fragment, and I want the "FOUR" to be just below "ONE" of fragment. If I set height of coordinator layout to wrap content, no fragment is shown at all.

Comment: please show the output you are getting vs the output you want in a image

Comment: @Shubhank added image of current output.

Comment: @featuresky why fragment.. why not use cards to achieve this

Comment: @OluDouglas Sorry, but what do U mean by using cards in place of fragments? Card == Cardview?

Comment: @featuresky how are you adding your fragments?

Comment: @OluDouglas using ViewPager adapter.

Comment: In that case.. adding a fragment to viewpager will only create an extra tab rather than add it below

Comment: try adding the fragment from within the first fragment

Comment: I didn't get U. I hv tabs which on click shows respective fragment.

Comment: now in that fragment which is the fragment at tab 1.. add another fragment to it

Comment: Thanx for suggestion but now I hv changed layout to simply hiding elements with visibility gone and be visible on on click event.